# how to send email in hidden window(Invisibly)

Tags: vb.net, email, sendmail

--sorry for editing the title--

I need to create a file to send an email in hidden mode(invisible window)

I have a code to send email when click a button
this is the code

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
```

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Mail As New MailMessage
    Mail.Subject = "test email"
    Mail.To.Add("youremail@googlemail.com")
    Mail.From = New MailAddress("youremail@googlemail.com")
    Mail.Body = "This is an ownage email using VB.NET"

    Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
    SMTP.EnableSsl = True
    SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
    SMTP.Port = "587"
    SMTP.Send(Mail)
End Sub
```

End Class

I want to Modify this code to send email invisibly in hidden window directly when running the file
please help
and sorry for changing the title

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to actually send a message from gmail (as opposed to sending a message via SMTP that looks like it was sent from gmail), you have to use the GMail API for .NET. You can find some [sample code that uses the Gmail API for .NET here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet), and you can find [information about using the API to send messages here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet to send mail from VB with attachment.

```
Public Sub SendMail(ByVal From As String, _
  ByVal sendTo As String, ByVal Subject As String, _
  ByVal Body As String, _
  Optional ByVal AttachmentFile As String = "", _
  Optional ByVal CC As String = "", _
  Optional ByVal BCC As String = "", _
  Optional ByVal SMTPServer As String = "")

    Dim myMessage As MailMessage

    Try
        myMessage = New MailMessage()
        With myMessage
            .To = sendTo
            .From = From
            .Subject = Subject
            .Body = Body
            .BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text
            'Custom mail message

            If CC <> "" Then .Cc = CC
            If BCC <> "" Then .Bcc = ""

            If FileExists(AttachmentFile) Then _
             .Attachments.Add(AttachmentFile)

        End With

        If SMTPServer <> "" Then _
           SmtpMail.SmtpServer = SMTPServer
        SmtpMail.Send(mailMessage)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: please tell me the problem you faced when using this code, may be some tweak needed.

Comment: @VishalKM Can I just ask, why do you have a `Try Catch` but then `Throw ex` when the exception's caught - it's pointless and it'll make the code harder to debug.